# More than one table header

Tags: html, xhtml

Can a table have more than one table header? I mean is it legal as per w3c standards either in html(4/5) or xhtml.

Comment: Why not run it through the validator and see for yourself? http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Yup, http://validator.w3.org/ (I'm fairly sure however that the answer is "no, it's not valid").

Comment: @Pekka i ran the test and it passed. So i can say it's valid

Comment: When I have the same problem, what I did was I applied the same table header styles for  the first table row in the table boday.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran a test as suggested by Pekka at validator.w3.org and it passed it all 3 HTML4 HTML5 XHTML 1.0.

The table can have more than 1 **TH** and **TBODY**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<!-- <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> -->
<!-- <!DOCTYPE html> -->

<html >
    <head><title>hi</title></head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>1 </th>
                <th>500 </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>1 </th>
                <th>500 </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just have to humbly point that this table has NO table header, it has just a few header cells, which are allowed to be placed in any section and in any number.

Answer (score 14):

**Table header** is expressed by the tag `<thead>`. The tag `<th>` is a **header cell**, so it is not clear what you meant, because in your example you have used only `<th>` elements placed in the *body* section.

The definitive source of wisdom is the [HTML5 specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-table-element), which says:

> [Content of the `<table>` element is:] optionally a caption element, followed by zero or more colgroup elements, followed optionally by a thead element, [...]

The same is said in [the HTML4 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.1), so, a table may have **only one header**.

On the other hand, the *header cell* elements (`<th>`) may be placed in **any section** of the table - header, footer or body. *(The same applies to data cells -`<td>`)*

A `<th>` in the body section represents a *row header* or *column header* or other headers, depending on the ["scope" attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-th-element) or context.

Comment: thanks i was under the impression that th was table header thanks for enlightening me . also is there a table footer.

Answer (score 0):

"Can a table have more than one table header" : **Yes**

"Is it legal as per w3c standards either in html(4/5) or xhtml" : **Yes**

Comment: Apparently, that is not true. See above.

Comment: I thought we were talking aboout the <thead> element...not the <th>

Comment: It seems possible even for theads: `When long tables are printed, the table head and foot information may be repeated on each page that contains table data.` (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3)

Comment: @Pekka: it means that **the header will be repeated** on every rendered page, and does not mean that you may define a different header for every page.